# How to change button icon when button clicked, python quickly

Tags: application-development, python, quickly

I'm trying to implement hide function in my application.
What I want is to have this little arrow ">" when is hide and "V" when is visible.
I know how to make it so its hides and shows but I need that little arrow to change whenever I click on it....

I'm using quickly and python to create my app.
I tried set_icon_from_stock function but it returns error:

```
AttributeError: 'ToolButton' object has no attribute 'set_icon_from_stock'
```

Above example of arrow I talking about.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an *Expander*, that's what Update Manager is using here, too. It's drawing the arrows and taking care about to show and hide what's inside.

[image: Screenshot Glade]

Comment: Oh my sweet lord ;-) I will never forget this again... thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtktoolbutton.html

> The icon of a gtk.ToolButton is determined by the properties
>   "icon-widget" and "stock-id". If "icon-widget" specifies a gtk.Widget,
>   that widget is used as the icon. If "icon-widget" is None, the icon is
>   determined by the stock item specified by "stock-id". If both
>   "icon-widget" and "stock-id" are None, the button does not have an
>   icon.
>
> The set_stock_id() method sets the "stock-id" property to the value of
>   stock_id. The stock item specified by stock_id is used to determine
>   the icon and label if not overridden by the "label" and "icon-widget"
>   properties. See the gtk.ToolButton() constructor for more information.
>
> The set_icon_name() method sets the "icon-name" property to the value
>   of icon_name. The themed icon name specified by icon_name is used to
>   determine the icon for the toolbutton if not overridden by the
>   "label", "stock-id" and "icon-widget" properties. See the
>   gtk.ToolButton() constructor for more information.